# Microsoft Bot Framework C# Async Issues

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webclient, botframework

I have an issue where a function is not being called. My guess is that it is a synchronization problem.

Here is the code:

```
await context.PostAsync("Foo Bar");
```

The function below doesn't seem to be called if I put it before or after the POST to the web server.

```
context.Call(new QuestionFourDialog(), this.QuestionFourResumeAfter);

Uri baseUri = new Uri("http://somedomain.com/");
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder($"{baseUri}/analytics/message?");

using (WebClient webclient = new WebClient())
{
    webclient.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    webclient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");

    string postBody = $"{{\"message\": \"{this.answer}\", \"key\": \"7F02D18E-88E7-486D-B51F-550118491CB1\"}}";

    webclient.UploadString(builder.Uri, postBody);
}
```

Is there a way I can call the POST code asynchronous or another way to solve this issue ?

Comment: How are you calling your function?

Comment: The code above is encapsulated in an async function  private async Task QuestionThreeResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result) it is a handler in a dialog chain. It is worth noting that if I comment out the webclient stuff it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced this line

```
webclient.UploadString(builder.Uri, postBody);
```

with

```
webclient.UploadStringAsync(builder.Uri, postBody);
```

and now it works perfectly.